# Ruby, php shell_exec and crontab not working correctly

Tags: php, ruby, debian, cron

```
   <?php


    $scan = shell_exec('ruby /home/user/wpscan/wpscan.rb --url site.com --enumerate vp --follow-redirection --threads 1000');

    And than...
     ... extracting data from array(); (explode("plugins:", 1))
     ... writing data[1] to txt file ...
     ... send mysql query with rule if() {} else {} ...
     ... unlink(); *.txt file ...
    ...that's all

     ?>
```

Hello. Have problems with running ruby script (wpscan) via crontab.
Adding it as root:

```
crontab -e
```

In cron:

```
* * * * php5 /home/user/wpscan/wpscan.php
```

When time comes - php script launching, but! Works all parts of script except `$scan` (part with ruby script doesn't work).

I tried to show script full path to ruby bin: "which ruby" and than I copied those path to php file.

Ruby installed under root, all scripts have maximum rights and where created under root. In scripts everywhere I'm using full paths to files I need to connect. I also tried to use full path for php5, but if trust syslog.log - it doesn't matter. Help me somebody please :)

Comment: Would you try to redirect ruby output to file and provide us with the explicit error message?

Comment: Arg... sorry, can't provide ruby script log output atm, can't access my server from work, tried but all ports except 80 are closed :( my bad, didn't check that before... sorry again
 But maybe any guesses ? :)

Comment: I’m not a fortune-teller :) You probably need to try to run `ruby /home/user/wpscan/wpscan.rb --url site.com --enumerate vp --follow-redirection --threads 1000` directly from root console and you’ll see, what’s the problem then. I guess, your root env lacks some gems needed to run your script properly.

Comment: if I run it from console - all works fine. It doesn't work only from cron when running through php script (maybe problem in shell_exec() ? )

Comment: If it perfectly runs **from a root console**, I can’t suggest anything until the output is demonstrated. Sorry for that. `shell_exec` should work fine, either.

Comment: Can you give me your email please? After work I will be able to get those log, so can send it to you, if you interested :) Will also add it here and solution, if will find any :) vlad144[at]tut.by

Comment: The part on ruby in php script is ignored when running from cron, no logs. But if run php5 test.php with shell_exec(ruby wpscan.rb) in console - all is fine. Dunno why, but it don't work only from cron.

Comment: Sounds weird. Would you try `shell_exec(ruby -e 'puts "I AM IN"')`?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/php-shell_exec-not-working-with-crontab-4175475760/

Comment: Also tried such thing:
$ruby = '/usr/local/bin/ruby';
$s = shell_exec("$ruby '/home/user/wpscan/wpscan.rb --url localhost --enumerate vp --threads 1000'");

Error: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory

P.S. I'm using full path both in php script and in cron

Comment: Arrgh. Looks like your `/home/user/wpscan/wpscan.rb` starts with hashbang `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. Try to remove this string. This must help.

Comment: I tried even to fix /usr/local/bin/ruby and changed
`#!/usr/bin/env ruby on #!/usr/local/bin/ruby`
Than I gave sudo without password for all users on folder with script,
also tried to manipulate with /usr/local/bin/ruby in script, tried to run php script with shell_exec of ruby from bash script... :) And there are no output as part with ruby not executing. But if I use short name 'ruby' in my php script - I have error, that ruby not found.

Comment: Let’s start from the scratch. How behaves `shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/ruby -e 'puts 1'")` in cron? Does it output 1?

Comment: The hashbang is only going to matter if you tell a shell to execute the script itself.  If you tell the shell to exeute _Ruby_ and pass the script's filename as a _parameter_, the hashbang means nothing.  Further, `/usr/bin/env ruby` is probably a _good_ way to execute ruby.  Try it yourself, I think you'll find it is very cooperative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have solved the problem.
 From what I understood, even if we run ruby script from cron, that doesn't mean that we have enough rights.
 So, first I made: added one fix to sudoers - providing root with NOPASSWD.
 Next: I check out all pathes in script as they must be full (i.e.: `/bin/php5 /home/test/test.php`)
 Than I add SUDO command in my script:

```
<?php
$test = shell_exec('sudo ruby /home/test/test.rb');
?>
```

Don't forget also chmod +x file.php

In cron I used:

```
crontab -e
*   *   *   *   *   php5 /home/test/test.php
```

And that's all :) Now all works fine.
 Some of my mistakes:

- don't forget to do test output from the file (i.e.: sh run.sh > test.txt);
- Use mail alerter with cron, it may help as well
- If you running something from cron - better use full path

  Thanks mudasobwa for advices and time :)

Comment: It's worth considering whether you want to give your PHP user unrestricted sudo access.  You can also restrict users to be able to sudo execute only _certain_ commands, and that is almost certainly what you should be doing here.

Comment: If you can see, I wrote about crontab, so some scripts running under root and users don't have access to them. All data in DB are filtered and only hostnames can be written, so no risks here. Only if find rce or sqli... but, as I wrote before - all data filtered.